# disable/hide confirm dialog box when deleting row from jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid and am looking to remove the confirm dialog box when deleting a row in jqGrid.  I have looked through the jqGrid code and documentation and don't seem to see anything that allows this behavior.  Is this something that would be posssible?

Comment: Instead of using a built-in delete button, you could always add a custom delete button, and then add whatever logic you need, which would include not displaying a confirmation dialog. See the [Custom Buttons](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) section in the documentation wiki to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with jqgrid, but I took a look at the documentation and had some thoughts.

1. Perhaps you can use `beforeShowForm` to cancel the dialog?
2. Use `afterShowForm` to programatically click confirm. Then perhaps use CSS so that the user never sees the dialog in the first place.

As stated I don't see an option in their docs to disable confirmation dialogs.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing&s[]=delete&s[]=row